# Induction and Compact induction of representations

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, representation-theory

Let $H \leq G$ be a subgroup of a finite group, $G.$  Suppose $(\sigma, W)$ is a representation of $H.$ Then we know that $Ind_H^G \sigma $ and $ind_H^G \sigma $ are isomorphic, where 
$$Ind_H^G \sigma = \{f:G \rightarrow W | f(hg) = \sigma (h) f(g) \ \  \forall h\in H, g \in G \}$$ and 
$$ind_H^G \sigma = \mathbb{C}[G] \otimes_{\mathbb{C}[H]} W.$$

My guess is that this can be generalized further where we can accommodate infinite groups and finite index subgroups with finite dimensional representations without much effort.

My question is how much more general can we go? Can the groups be algebraic groups in particular? Can we have subgroups which are not necessarily finite indexed and infinite dimensional representations? What combinations of these parameters work?

Any references will be appreciated.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to be a bit careful if you want to do this for algebraic groups. If you take only rational maps in the first definition, then you get the "correct" way to do this for algebraic groups, but it will no longer be the same as the second definition. Note that the first definition is (at least in most cases though I might miss some odd ones) left exact, whereas the second one is right exact. In general, you should not expect to have an exact induction.

Comment: But then can we say something for Lie groups? Then we will need to restrict functions to $L^2$ but then do we have an isomorphism? Or in what cases can we say something concretely?

Comment: I am not that familiar with how things look for Lie groups. In some sense this is a reason why the first definition is a very nice one. It allows one to restrict to maps respecting some underlying topology or geometry, and this is not really possible with the second definition (and usually this restriction will be what makes the resulting representation satisfy whatever extra conditions one requires, such as smooth or rational or whatever).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\def\Ind{\mathop{\mathrm{Ind}}\nolimits} \def\ind{\mathop{\mathrm{ind}}\nolimits}
\def\Hom{\mathop{\mathrm{Hom}}\nolimits}$$

Let me talk about these two functors for a bit.

The first thing I should mention is that while the representations $\Ind_{H}^{G} \sigma$ and $\ind_{H}^{G} \sigma$ are isomorphic (for finite groups $G$ and $H$), they are not necessarily canonically isomorphic. The reason that the representations turn out to be isomorphic is because the representation category of a finite group over a field of characteristic prime to its order is semisimple. What this implies in particular is that for representations $V, W$ of $G$,

$$\Hom_{G}(V, W) \cong \Hom_{G}(W, V)$$

Now, the first functor $\Ind$, is right adjoint to restriction. If $W$ is a representation of $H$ and $V$ a representation of $G$, then

$$\Hom_{H}(V, W) \cong \Hom_{G}(V, \Ind_{H}^{G} W).$$

Here the isomorphism sends $\phi : V \rightarrow W$ to $\Phi$ which sends $v$ to the function $g \mapsto \phi(g \cdot v)$.

On the other hand, the second functor $\ind$, is left adjoint to restriction i.e.

$$\Hom_{H}(W, V) \cong \Hom_{G}(\ind_{H}^{G} W, V)$$

where $\phi: W \rightarrow V$ is sent to $\Phi$ which maps $g \otimes w$ to $g\cdot \phi(w)$.

Since $\Hom$ spaces can just be switched around in the semisimple representation category of a finite group, the two functors give isomorphic representations in this case. But the isomorphism

$$\Hom_{G}(V, W) \cong \Hom_{G}(W, V)$$

is very non-canonical. You have to choose some isomorphism and there isn't any particularly good one. So, the functors $\Ind$ and $\ind$ are not isomorphic.

I can try and explain where these functors extend and where they don't when you impose additional conditions on the groups.

1. Infinite groups with finite index: If $G$ and $H$ are infinite groups with $H$ finite index in $G$, both functors definitely exist and make sense at the level of finite dimensional representations. These functors will probably give isomorphic representations if $\sigma$ is semisimple. However, I am not sure if the representations will be isomorphic if $\sigma$ is not semisimple.
2. Algebraic Groups: For finite dimensional representations of an algebraic group, $\Ind$ makes perfect sense as long as you restrict to regular maps (and is often called geometric induction) and the field is algebraically closed. There's actually a slightly better description of this functor which works also in the non-algebraically closed setting: given a representation $H$ of $W$, we can form a vector bundle over the variety $G/H$

$$G \times_{H} W := G \times W/(gh, w) ~ (g, hw).$$

(This definition can easily be upgraded to a scheme theoretic one.) Then, we can define $\Ind_{H}^{G} W$ as the global sections of this vector bundle. This has the same adjointness property as in the finite group setting.

Now, $\ind$ as defined does not make sense for finite dimensional representations of an algebraic group. One reason is easy to see: $\mathbb{C}[G]$ (the algebraic coordinate ring) has infinite rank over $\mathbb{C}[H]$ so the tensor product

$$\mathbb{C}[G] \otimes_{\mathbb{C}[H]} W$$

is not a finite dimensional representation of $G$. But the failure of finite dimensionality is not too bad here because $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is a sum of its finite dimensional rational subrepresentations. Hence, $\ind_{H}^{G} W$ is also a sum of finite dimensional subrepresentations and the functor can thus be defined on the ind-completion of the category of rational representations. In this setting, $\ind$ satisfies the same adjointness property as in the case of finite groups.

But now, we need to take infinite dimensional representations so even when the algebraic groups $G$ and $H$ are reductive and the representation category is semisimple, I do not think the two functors will always give isomorphic representations on the infinite dimensional representations. **I am not 100% sure on this though.**

3. Lie groups: I believe a similar situation happens as in the algebraic case by always using $L^{2}$ functions, either in the definition of $\Ind$ or in the definition of $\mathbb{C}[G]$ and $\mathbb{C}[H]$.

**Disclaimer: I do not know much about $L^{2}$-representations of Lie groups.**

4. Lie algebras: The second functor $\ind$ has a similar definition for Lie algebras by replacing $\mathbb{C}[G]$ with the universal enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak{g})$ (and doing the same for $H$). This is a very important construction when studying semisimple Lie algebras as it's used to define Verma modules.
5. Associative algebras: $\ind$ is basically extension of scalars for algebras. If you have an algebra $A$ with a subalgebra $B$ and a left $B$-module $W$, then you can define an $A$-module $\ind_{B}^{A} W : = A \otimes_{B} W$. This defines a functor which is left adjoint to restriction.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. That is really helpful. Also could  you suggest me some reference for studying representations of algebraic groups? Thanks again.

Comment: @MakarandSarnobat The three books titled "Linear Algebraic Groups" by Borel, Humphreys and Springer all give a decent introduction to the subject. The "usual" reference for more advanced questions is Jantzen's "Representations of Algebraic Groups" though this has somewhat higher requirements.

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh Thanks alot!